# Encrypt user password with jquery and decrypt it with C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, encryption

- I don't want to use SSL to encrypt signup and signin forms for a website I'm building.
- I don't have money to pay for a certificate.
- I need to use encryption with jQuery and decryption with C# in my asp.net website.

Does someone have an example and how is it secure to adopt this method?

Comment: Not secure at all. Next!

Comment: SSL witch is a **Secure Socket Layer** should never be compared to encryption, Its totally different, SSL Protects data witch is being transmitted from one entity to another, where as encryption protects the data from being read.

Comment: You can get a SSL certificate from godaddy.com from about 50 dollars. Buying such a certificate is a lot cheaper then developing your own encryption.

Comment: @Svisstack, yea I jumped the gun a little, changed.

Comment: SSL ensures security and integrity of the data. Also, the sender gets authenticated by the help of the certificate authority (such as Verisign).

Comment: Don't indent your question - the editor reads that as `code`.

Answer (score 15):

If you're not using SSL, then you're not secure, but that's not the only reason.

[SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) protects the actual communication, whereas encryption protects the data you are communicating. You should not even be encrypting the passwords at all. You should be making a **hardened hash** of the information. A [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) is a one-way function (cannot be reversed), whereas [encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption) is two-way function(can be reversed). Hash hardening and use includes:

- Iterating over a hash built for speed, such as [`SHA512`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) a couple of thousand times or using something like [BCrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt).
- Use a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) - Something like a 64-bit array of jumble per user, stored in the database will do it
- Encrypt the keys and salts in the DB using a key in the application layer - This means if your database is taken, they would still need the key from the application layer to access the raw hash information, as well as the salts.

You have to remember that security is built in layers. By skipping SSL, you're skipping a large portion of it. At the very least you can use `makecert` to [create a self-signed certificate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3.aspx). All that will happen is that the user will be warned about it. A good SSL certificate can cost as little as $12.99 on [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com/Compare/gdcompare_ssl.aspx). I recommend getting one as well as implementing the above.

Comment: *"If that key information is accessible, you can kiss your security goodbye completely."* This is only true for synchronous encryption, not for asynchronous encryption. But the performance of asynchronous encryption in JavaScript is bad. If you use asynchronous encryption like RSA or any other Public-Key-System, you can publish your encryption key. You need to keep only the decryption key secret.

Comment: @jig - Removed that end part. Not as relevant to the rest of the answer in any case.

Comment: @jig - Hehe, thanks. I should have been more specific in any case.

Comment: @jigfox Just a *little* correction: I think you should replace *synchronous* / *asynchronous* with *symmetric* / *asymmetric* in your first comment

Comment: @Giu, you're absolutely right. Sorry about this, but english is not my first language and so sometimes I make mistakes. Sadly, it's too late to edit my comment.

Comment: @jigfox that's no problem at all; I know you didn't write it intentionally, since the rest of your comment is content-wise completely correct. And your English is good, too, so definitely don't worry about that :)

Answer (score 6):

You can do SSL without paying for a certificate, and this method get you secure only browser get information about your certificate is not qualified.

Read about this http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not secure at all. 
SSL really is the way to go; if you can't afford a certificate, you can always make your own. Obviously those won't validate up to one of the trusted root authorities, but they are just as secure - the identity of your website will not be confirmed by a trusted third party, but the connection itself will be just as securely encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

By not using SSL you're opening up your code to network sniffing attacks. Encrypting on the client side won't do any good either.

Unfortunately there's no safe way around it without getting a valid certificate. This approach would be unsecure.

Comment: A self-hosted certificate will be just as secure, as long as the DNS doesn't get hacked.

Comment: @tdammers - true, but I was assuming the OP wanted this for a public facing site instead of self-signed.

Comment: Yeah, there's the annoying browser security warnings... if the site is important enough to be encrypted like this, then whoever wants it should just pay for the certificate I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the security concerns of the other individuals, if you're hell-bent-for-leather on doing it this way, you may attempt to employ a custom PKI interface. You will have to research a little more deeply on the code necessary to accomplish this but here is a link to describe the public key structure:

[Public Key Cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)

So if you manage to code up a public key RSA algorithm in jquery, you should be to match its private key decryption in C# without difficulty. This is not a recommendation because this really is only "security through obfuscation" (which is not security at all).

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt the form data with Javascript. This can be done, see [http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/aes.html)). If data is encrypted with a key, then you'll have to store that key in javascript code and also in server-side code. Since javascript code will be client-side and key will be public, that's not secure at all :). The same is also valid for asymmetric encryption. Different data can be encrypted with the same key and sent to server.

SSL is designed to overcome security problems on the web, using public key cryptograpy and symmetric encryption tehcniques. Middle-man attack is prevented. Using SSL, you can be sure that your data is secure, not altered through the way and there is a 3rd party, certificate authority, which says that you're the person you claim to be.

If you say that I can put the key or encryption code in an applet or active-x or flash swf object and use obfuscation to secure the code, that may be a way. But again this approach is open to attacks and not secure. Obfuscation does not guarantee that your key or algorithm is safe, just hardens the cracker's job to get the key.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) for authentication. This would not provide privacy but a sniffer (guy looking into then network traffic) would not be able to get the passwords nor login impersonating an authentic user. When I it does not provide privacy I mean the sniffer will see all the transferred content but not the password.

SSL is of course very secure, but an overkill for many applications.